# How can I discover if a mapper has been created for two classes in Orika?

Tags: java, orika

So I am writing a Telematics application and we are slowly building up mappers for DTOs. There will soon be over 100 but right now we have 3. We want to send all messages to our mapper but when we do and `Orika` doesn't know about it, it throws an exception.

I need a `.isMapperAvailable(class, class)` method but cannot find one. I did find a `.existsRegisteredMapper(Type, Type)` but can't figure out how it works. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use it like this:

```
MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();

ClassMapBuilder<Foo, Bar> map = mapperFactory.classMap(Foo.class, Bar.class);

Type<Foo> fooType = map.getAType();
Type<Bar> barType = map.getBType()

boolean exists = mapperFactory.existsRegisteredMapper(fooType, barType, false);
```

Comment: This does work but is quite messy.  Thanks for the input but I am hoping for something better...

Comment: You don't need to create a class map to get Type of class, just use a TypeFactory.valueOf

Comment: Bingo!  this.mf.existsRegisteredMapper(TypeFactory.valueOf(from.getClass()), TypeFactory.valueOf(to), false);  This works great.  Thanks @SidiMohamed !

Answer (score 0):

There is one flaw with `existsRegisteredMapper()` method. 
Suppose you want to different type of mapping for `A` to `B` and `B` to `A`.
In this case, this method returns true for both method calls:

```
mapperFactory.existsRegisteredMapper(A, B, true);

mapperFactory.existsRegisteredMapper(B, A, true);
```